# HTTP timeout when calling soap method

Tags: .net, web-services, soap, httprequest, soapfault

I have a .net web service and it is not accessible since a week ago from some countries, also the strange issue is that the clients in that country can send http calls to my site successfully, any issue?

Comment: Putting a questionmark at the end doesn't make it a question. You really need to provide more information, errors, tracerouters, whatever to be able to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Help us to help you ! In other words provide more info about your question!